# Case-sensitive substitutions with gsub

Tags: ruby, regex

As an exercise, I'm working on an accent translation dictionary. My dictionary is contained in a hash, and I'm thinking of using `#gsub!` to run inputted strings through the translator.

I'm wondering if there's any way to make the substitutions case-sensitive.  For example, I want `"didja"` to translate to `"did you"` and `"Didja"` to translate to `"Did you"`, but I don't want to have to create multiple dictionary entries to deal with case.

I know I can use regex syntax to *find* strings to replace case-insensitively, with `str.gsub!(/#{x}/i,dictionary[x])` where `x` is a variable. The problem is that this replaces `"Didja"` with `"did you"`, rather than matching the original case.

Is there any way to make it match the original case?

Comment: Suppose the dictionary contained `"aardvark" -> "ardvark"`. Would `"Aardvark"` be converted to `"Ardvark"` or `"ardvark"`? For `"iphone -> phone"`, would `"iPhone"` be converted to `"Phone"` or `"phone"`? In other words, I think you need to be more precise about the rules.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Suppose we have:

- a method `to_key` that converts a string `str` to a key in a hash `DICTIONARY`; and
- a method `transform` that converts the pair `[str, DICTIONARY[to_key(str)]]` to the replacement for `str`.

Then `str` is to be replaced with:

```
transform(str, DICTIONARY[to_key(str)]])
```

Without lose of generality, I think we can assume that `DICTIONARY`'s keys and values are all of the same case (say, lower case) and that `to_key` is simply:

```
def to_key(str)
  str.downcase
end
```

So all that is necessary is to define the method `transform`. However, the specification provided does not imply a unique mapping. We therefore must decide what `transform` should do.

For example, suppose the rule is simply that, if the first character of `str` and the first character of the dictionary value are both letters, the latter is to be converted to upper case if the former is upper case. Then:

```
def transform(str, dict_value)
  (str[0] =~ /[A-Z]/) ? dict_value.capitalize : dict_value 
end
```

(I originally had `dict_value[0] = dict_value[0].upcase if...`, but came to my senses after reading @sawa's answer.)

Note that if `DICTIONARY['cat'] => 'dog'`, `'Cat'` will be converted to `'Dog'`.

One might think that another possibility is that all characters of `str` that are letters should maintain their case. This is problematic, however, as the dictionary mapping may (without further specification) remove letters, and it may not be clear from `DICTIONARY[str]` which letters of `str` were removed, some of which may be lower case and others upper case.

Answer (score 2):

It is not clear what capitalization patterns you have in mind. I assume that you only need to deal with words that are all low case or all low case except the first letter.

```
str.gsub!(/#{x}/i){|x| x.downcase! ? dictionary[x].capitalize : dictionary[x]}
```

Answer (score 1):

I don't think this is possible since in this scenario you need to specify the exact string that must take place of the replaced string.

With that in mind, this is the best I can suggest:

```
subs = {'didja' => 'did you'}
subs.clone.each{ |k, v| subs[k.capitalize] = v.capitalize }

# if you want to replace all occurrences i.e. even substrings:
regex = /#{subs.keys.join('|')}/

# if you want to remove complete words only: (as the Tin man points out)
regex = /\b(?:#{subs.keys.join('|')})\b/ # \b checks for word-boundaries

"didja Didja".gsub(regex, subs)
```

**Update:**

Because in your example, the case-sensitive character isn't to be replaced by another value, you could use this:

```
regex = /(?<=(d))idja/i # again, keep in mind the substrings
"didja Didja".gsub(regex, "id you")
```

Comment: Don't use `/#{subs.keys.join('|')}/` unless you intend to clean up sub-string substitutions also. Instead, search for whole words using something like `/\b(?:#{subs.keys.join('|')})\b/`